# How to have additional fields in SQLFORM that are not in table in web2py?

Tags: forms, web2py

I have a form for creating new records in a table generated using SQLFORM.  One of the fields of the table will not be directly exposed to the user but instead created based on the values of a few other input elements which themselves are not part of the table.

How do I add additional fields to an SQLFORM that are not part of the table and do not need to be part of the database insert?  And where would be the place to calculate the non-exposed field before inserting into the database?

(A hypothetical example would be having latitude and longitude coordinate fields in the table but no address field.  In this example, would need address field on create form that could be used to geocode and store coordinates in lat/lng fields)

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved this was by using `SQLFORM.factory` instead of `SQLFORM`.

1. I extracted the fields defined on my table

```
fields = [field for field in db.customer]
```

2. appended the new fields I wanted

```
fields += [
    Field('customer_type','string', label=T('Customer Type'),
         requires=IS_IN_SET(customer_types, zero=None, sort=False)),
    Field('another_field','string', label=T('Another Field')),
    ]
```

3. used SQLFORM.factory to generate the form

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
    *fields,
    formstyle='bootstrap',
    _class='customer form-horizontal',
    table_name='customer'
    )
```

* note the asterisk before `fields` is necessary

4. still used `form.process().accepted` but then calculated what I needed to and then manually handled the database insert

```
if form.process().accepted:
    ...
    form.vars.some_nonwritable_field = calculate_complicated_value()
    db.customer.insert(**db.customer._filter_fields(form.vars))
    ...
```

`_filter_fields` prevents the dynamically added fields from being part of the insert.

This way I could add additional field to the form that were validated but not part of the insert.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of web2py you can do it shorter:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
    db.table,

    Field('my_field_1'),
    Field('my_field_2'),
)
```